# Calculating price list + discount after 2/5 items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a interactive price list for a friend of mine.
She want a price list, where the customer can check her prices. If the customer clicks on multiple options the price is automatically calculated. There are two price lists. One for Woman and one for Man.
That is working so far.

The problem which I've got is: When I change between Woman and Man, the price is still in the "total" field.
But the biggest problem for me is, that when the customer selects 2-4 options he get a discount of 10% and 5 or more options he get 20% discount.

Here you can see my [codepen](http://codepen.io/Nerd/pen/eNqjoZ)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');

    })
})

$(function() {
    $('input').click(function() {

        var total = 0;
        $('input:checked').each(function(index, item) {
            total += parseFloat(item.value);
        });
        $('.total').text(total);
    });
});

$('#head_checkbox').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.person').attr('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('.person').attr('checked', false);
    }
});

$('.person').click(function() {
    var total_length = $('.person').length;
    var total_checked_length = $('.person:checked').length;

    if (total_length == total_checked_length) {
        $('#head_checkbox').attr('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('#head_checkbox').attr('checked', false);
    }
});

var checked = false;
$('.all').click(function() {
    e = $(this).attr('name');
    checked = !checked;
    $('input[class=' + e).prop('checked', checked);
});
```

Comment: For the first problem, you should change the `input:checked` selector to only include inputs in the active tab.

Comment: He gets a discount for 2-3 options, 5 options, but not 4?

Comment: Oh, of course also for 4.

Comment: *When I change between Woman and Man, the price is still in the "total" field.* Should it not? It behaves like a shopping cart. When you move to a different **page** the cart content is preserved, let alone switching to a different **tab**.

Comment: The price list is either for a man or for a woman. The price list is only there to inform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixes for "total" filed on different tabs:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        tab_1_total = 0;
        tab_2_total = 0;
        tab_id = "";
        $('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
                tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

                $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
                $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

                $(this).addClass('current');
                $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');

                if( tab_id == "tab-1") {
                    $('.total').text(tab_1_total);
                }

                else if( tab_id == "tab-2") {
                    $('.total').text(tab_2_total);
                }
        })
})

$(function() {
        $('input').click(function() {

                var total = 0;
                var option_count = 0;   

                $('.tab-content.current input:checked').each(function(index, item) {
                        total += parseFloat(item.value);
                        option_count++;
                });
                // Apply multiple product discount
                if (option_count >= 5) {
                        total *= .80;
                } else if (option_count >= 2) {
                        total *= .90;
                }

                total = total.toFixed(2);
                $('.total').text(total);

                if( tab_id == "tab-1") {
                    tab_1_total = total;
                }

                else if( tab_id == "tab-2") {
                    tab_2_total = total;                    
                }

        });
});

$('#head_checkbox').on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('.person').attr('checked', true);
        } else {
                $('.person').attr('checked', false);
        }
});

$('.person').click(function() {
        var total_length = $('.person').length;
        var total_checked_length = $('.person:checked').length;

        if (total_length == total_checked_length) {
                $('#head_checkbox').attr('checked', true);
        } else {
                $('#head_checkbox').attr('checked', false);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Change the selector to only match inputs in the current tab.

2) Count the number of checked options, and apply a discount to the total when you're done.

```
$(function() {
    $('input').click(function() {

        var total = 0;
        var option_count = 0;
        $('.tab-content.current input:checked').each(function(index, item) {
            total += parseFloat(item.value);
            option_count++;
        });
        // Apply multiple product discount
        if (option_count >= 5) {
            total *= .80;
        } else if (option_count >= 2) {
            total *= .90;
        }
        $('.total').text(total);
    });
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to limit the digits after the comma to 2?